# マッチングサイトのウェブアプリを作ろうと思ってますが、、MODELの考え方(Railsにて）

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

はじめまして、あけましておめでとうございます。

当方、ノンプログラマーの初心者です。

質問があります。 
マッチングサイト系のウェブサービスを作ってみようとトライしていますが、 
アプリを設計する上でデータベースの考え方としてどのように設計していこうか困っています。

**「ユーザーが登録されていて、興味があればリクエストを送り、マッチング成功すれば、 
メッセージのやり取りを行う。」 
という処理を行いたいです。**

とりあえずデーターベースは、 
・Userの登録情報のデータ 
・投稿（メッセージ）のデータ

のモデルを作成するつもりですが、 
マッチングのリクエスト（許可）を取る仕組みをどの様に 
考えればいいのか。

とりあえず、私が考えているのは、 
ユーザーのデータベースにリクエストがあったことを知らせるカラムを作り、 
その情報がお互いのデータベースに入れば、 
投稿のデータを使用可能にする。 
それだと、複数人のリクエストに対応できなさそうで、マッチングのモデルを作成し、
そこで管理するというイメージで考えています。

どうでしょうか？！ 
しょうもない質問かもしれませんが、 
ご教授願います！m(__)m

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/4929　マルチポスト

Comment: 趣旨に反するとのことで、コメントは削除しました。初心者だからといって、マナー違反が許されるわけではありません。ご一読ください。http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1766/

Comment: 注意するにしても人を挑発するような書き方をする方も、マナー違反だと思いますが？　ex 自分の頭で考えましょう

Comment: 仰るとおりです。それもありコメントを削除しました。規約違反かもしれませんね。

Comment: わかりました。私も大人気なかったです。忠告真摯に受け止めます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

一案ということで。変数名やメソッド名は適当に付けてるので、(英語として) あまり良くないかも。

1. Scaffold でモデルなどを作ります。MatchRequest はリクエストしたユーザ (request_user_id), リクエスト対象のユーザ (target_user_id) を持つとします。MatchRequest で相互にリクエストすることで、マッチ完了というルールにします。

   ```
   % rails c
   > rails g scaffold User name:string
   > rails g scaffold MatchRequest request_user_id:integer target_user_id:integer
   ```
2. とりあえずユーザを作ります。

   ```
   User.create :name => "Nanoha"
   User.create :name => "Fate"
   User.create :name => "Hayate"
   ```
3. [Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) を設定しましょう。MatchRequest を経由して、UserとUserが N:N の関係になります。

   ```
   # app/models/user.rb
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :sent_match_requests, :class_name => MatchRequest, :foreign_key => :request_user_id
     has_many :targeted_match_requests, :class_name => MatchRequest, :foreign_key => :target_user_id
   ```

   ```
   # app/models/match_request.rb
   class MatchRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :request_userm, :class_name => User
     belongs_to :target_user, :class_name => User
   end
   ```
4. MatchRequest の情報を入れます。

   ```
   MatchRequest.create :request_user_id => 1, :target_user_id => 2
   MatchRequest.create :request_user_id => 2, :target_user_id => 1
   MatchRequest.create :request_user_id => 3, :target_user_id => 1
   MatchRequest.create :request_user_id => 2, :target_user_id => 3
   MatchRequest.create :request_user_id => 3, :target_user_id => 2
   ```
5. 確認します。

   ```
   % rails c
   > fate = User.find_by :name => "Fate"
   > fate.sent_match_requests
   # => 略
   > fate.targeted_match_requests
   # => 略
   ```
6. マッチしたユーザを返す User#matchers を作ります。ActiveRecord を真面目に使えばもう少しスマートに書けそう。

   ```
   # app/models/user.rb
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     ...
     def matchers
       requester_ids = targeted_match_requests.pluck(:request_user_id)
       sent_match_requests
         .eager_load(:target_user)
         .select { |r| requester_ids.include? r.target_user_id }
         .map { |r| r.target_user }
     end
   end
   ```
7. 確認します。マッチしたユーザが表示されました。他のユーザでも試してみてください。

   ```
   > fate.matchers
   => [#<User:0x007fac3075f7b8
     id: 1,
     name: "Nanoha",
     created_at: Sun, 04 Jan 2015 13:07:30 UTC +00:00,
     updated_at: Sun, 04 Jan 2015 13:07:30 UTC +00:00>,
    #<User:0x007fac3076f2f8
     id: 3,
     name: "Hayate",
     created_at: Sun, 04 Jan 2015 13:07:38 UTC +00:00,
     updated_at: Sun, 04 Jan 2015 13:07:38 UTC +00:00>]
   ```

Comment: yasuさん、ありがとうございます！
ちょっと初学者なため、
少し研究してからレス返させていただきます！！
踏み込んだ回答ができなくてすいません。

Comment: @yasuさん、やっと理解できるようになりました。
アソシエーションの自己結合でやるんですね、
わざわざコード書いて頂いてありがとうございます。

これを応用してちょっと作ってみようかとおもいます！

ちなみに、
http://railsguides.jp/association_basics.html#自己結合
http://www.coma-tech.com/archives/258/
などを見て理解できるようになりました。

ありがとうございますm(__)m

Answer (score 1):

カラムでやるのは難しいでしょう。

つながりのリクエストをどちらからいつ出したのか、などの扱いもあります。
誰から誰へというリクエストを扱うテーブルと、出されたリクエストを承認した時にレコードを挿入する繋がりのテーブルの2つに分けて扱うのが素直ではないでしょうか。

データ量が数百万件などになってくるとまた別の問題も発生しますが、おそらくそこまでは考慮しないでいいということだと思います。

データベースの設計についての柔らかい読み物をひとつ紹介します。よろしければ参考にどうぞ。

- http://www.mahoutsukaino.com/ac/ac2002/datamodel/d01/d01.htm

Comment: そうですか、、データベース設計の読み物ありがとうございます。
参考になりました！すごくわかりやすかったです！